# Installing Air application from DVD Drive

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

We have an Adobe Air application. Now we'll make DVD's an ship them to potential clients.
How can I be certain that the client can open this .air file if they don't have adobe Air installed?
Also I saw that Mac's often wanna open .air files in applescript(also if Air is installed).

I know that there are install badge. But I think they don't work with local .air files. Or is there a way to install a local .air with a badge?

Which solution would you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Using the earlier version of AIR and Flex Builder you can export in .exe, .mdg and .deb...

Comment: yeah u saw this, and packaged them in a .exe and .dmg. The problem here is, that my air application is about 700mb big (many high res pictures). If i start the .exe he need about 2 minutes (i think because of the big size) to just open the installer window and see that something happens. So in this case it's impossible to ship it like that. I can not execlude this high res images and download them later because this application needs to be run offline as well. By they way, the .dmg was always damaged and can't open it.

Answer (score 1):

the .air installer file (or .exe, .dmg, .deb native air installer file) will try to download AIR from the internet during installation if it detects that AIR is not currently installed on the users computer.  installation will fail if AIR is not already installed and there is no internet connection.

since you want to run the application from your DVD and not have to force your users to install the application on their local drives, you could write just the application to the DVD in an "installed" state for each OS that you are targeting.

if you are concerned that one of your clients will not have AIR installed on their systems or have an internet connection, you could simply bundle the most recent AIR 2.5 installers for Mac, PC and Linux on your DVD, which you can find on Adobe's site here:  http://get.adobe.com/air/otherversions/ but if you're going to do that you might also want to include your application installer file(s) as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem here is, that my air application is about 700mb big (many high res pictures).

Perhaps you can use modules or RSLs to move resources out of the application and have them downloaded (and cached?) on startup.